# How should I be updating data with AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller

I am making a rails MVC style application.

When I am loading the pages, the controller gets the data from the model and forwards it to the view and the view renders itself.

However, I am wondering what the appropriate way is to interact between javascript and my database.

Say the user is playing a game and he has a bunch of clues on the screen. Clicking a clue will move it to his clue box and needs to update the UserClues model to add the clue.

The user also needs to be able to remove clues where the clue gets removed etc...

This needs to happen via AJAX.

I am wondering what the appropriate approach is.

Say he got his page from /Investigation which loaded the page using the InvestigationController.

Should the InvestigationController be the one calling the model to add/remove the clues, or should some sort of data controller do it.

For example:

```
/Investigation/AddClue
```

or another controller

```
/User/Clues/Add
```

The reason I am asking is I have a lot of data on my pages that is created/added/modified and I am wondering if my routes/controllers should be separate for data manipulation and pages, or if I should have a controller for each page and it also manages what the user can do on that page (like add / remove clues to and from a ClueBox)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you will want to have a separate controller for each resource. Even though your current view is in the context of the `Investigations`, controller, dealing with clues should have its own resource. Otherwise things can get complex. If the clues are investigation specific, then you can scope them under the Investigation URL.

```
resources :investigations do
  resources :clues
end
```

This will give you something like `/investigations/1/clues/1`, but this maybe not be necessary, and I would avoid nesting unless required.

The controller can then respond in the correct format. In this case Rails UJS provides you with the tools you need. You can render a `create.js.erb` or `destroy.js.erb` templates to handle user actions. The templates would have the required JavaScript and dynamic code to update the screen state.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, try to use Rails' RESTful routes. In this case, that probably means line in your routes file that looks something like:

```
resources users do
  resources clues
end
```

In your users/clues_controller.rb file, put in actions for the different AJAX requests, like `create` to add a clue to a user (via a POST request), `destroy` action to remove a clue from user (via a DELETE request, might need to simulate with POST + "_method=delete" parameter).